# getting null/ undefined while reassigning variable in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a test array :
test = null;

I have created a function and i am reassigning values to test array , ALthou it says null array / undefined array

```
abcd(){
    this.dataService.getAirport().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.airportData = data.data.data.metaDataRows;
        this.countryData = data.data.data.metaDataFields[0].column;
         const airConNames = this.countryData.values;
         this.test = [];
         this.test.push({name:'Select a Country', id:'0'});
         //this.test = [{name:'Select a Country', id:'0'}];
         console.log(this.test);
         airConNames.forEach(function(entry) {
           //console.log(entry.name);
           //console.log(entry.country_id);
          this.test = [{name : entry.name, id : entry.country_id}];
         });
        console.log(this.test); // this is null
      },
      (error) => {
        this.dataService.handleServiceError(error.message, this.TAG);
      }
    );
      console.log(this.test); //this is null
 }
```

The console shows null,

where am i  going wrong

Comment: which `console.log` statement shows null?

Comment: One above foreach has values.... after the foreach just before the function closes shows null

Comment: I've edited the code to reflect that

Comment: Are you sure that it definitely shows `null`? I'm struggling to see a way for that to be possible, nothing above that should be able to show return `null`

Comment: thats right it shows null and even the last console.

Comment: it doesnt print the console inside foreach - getting an error  :"Cannot read property 'test' of undefined","name":"TypeError","stack":"TypeError:

Comment: Because you may have a different `this` in each of these scopes. Bind `this` to a variable and use that.

Comment: Can u show an example??

Comment: No, don't have the time, sorry. You can check if your instances of `this` in each scope yield the same result by printing them. You can also use nullchecks on each property, to find out which is causing you errors. If `this` in your innermost scope is not the same as `this` in your outer scopes, then the outer `console.log` calls won't know anything about `this.test`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, inside the `foreach` loop, you're setting `this.test` to a new array every time.  You should be doing a `this.test.push()` operation or using rest arguments `this.test = [{ ... }, ...this.test];` (depending on if you wanted to put the rest on the end (unshift) or in the beginning (push).

Next, the `this` context is not what you're expecting because you're using `airConNames.forEach(function(entry) { ... })`.  Try using arrow function syntax `airConNames.forEach((entry) => {`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target.

Not seeing why `this.test` is null after the foreach, that is odd.
Try:

```
this.test = airConNames.map(entry => ({ name: entry.name, id: entry.country_id }));
this.test.unshift({ name: 'Select a Country', id:'0' });
```

Comment: I tried which solved the console output for data in foreach, however the last console log still shows null

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing anything that would explain that behavior. Updated answer to try a `.map` operation instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 airConNames.forEach(function(entry) {
       //console.log(entry.name);
       //console.log(entry.country_id);
       // push new values into your test array:
      this.test.push({name : entry.name, id : entry.country_id});
     });
    console.log(this.test); // this is null
  },
```

This context inside the for loop refers to the forEach function scope and that is the reason this.test is not same as this.test outside the loop where console.log is printed.

If you want to make sure it's the same instance of variable declared above use the fat arrow notation => . 
An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.
Ex:

```
airConNames.forEach((entry) => {
   //console.log(entry.name);
    //console.log(entry.country_id);
// push new values into your test array:
  this.test.push({name : entry.name, id : entry.country_id});
```

});

See more on arrow function here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions